# Using Flask as a Webhook for my Test Script

Tags: python, flask, webhooks, python-unittest

I have to create a test script that basically has to send a request to a TCP server which will start performing (Or queuing) an action and then it will respond with a basic acknowledgement that the request was received. The third party will perform the action and after a few seconds (5 to 10) it will make an async call to my flask webhook to report the result of the action, then the test script will evaluate the response and continue with another action/test.

My biggest challenge is how to wait for that webhook request to proceed with the test.

I have thought of a cycle with a timeout that will check if the webhook was called every x seconds, but this will mean a waste time and resources.

Any suggestions for a notification method between my Test Script and the webhook?

Comment: The _waste of time_ is inevitable, your third party server takes 5 to 10 seconds to respond. The _waste of resources_ is probably negligible as well. Have you considered using a loop with `time.sleep()`?

Comment: That is the approach I was thinking of doing, a loop with a sleep of 1 second and a timeout of say 10 seconda or less. But it just feels such a waste of resources doing 4 or 5 requests for nothing... I also tried using flask so the third party service will talk to a webhook but I haven't found a way to make my script stop and wait for the webhook to receive the request.